# JavaScript. jQuery import

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me please! Why this code not work? It does not show alert.

```
var jqueryScript = document.createElement('script');
jqueryScript.src =                 
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
jqueryScript.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqueryScript);

$(function() {
    $("#main").click(function() {
        alert("asdasd");
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're not accounting for the time it takes to load jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because jQuery lib is not loaded as it loads asynchronously made that way, and no one can guarantee you when it will load on time, which is not that way if you load it by `<script>` tag, so `$(function() { ... });` won't work as `$` which represents `$.jQuery(` is not initialized yet. If you execute the script second time without reloading the page, it will work, as jQuery will be loaded from the first execution, even its made in wrong time.